# Wordpress signup/signin and stay logged in on a different url (SSO-like)

Tags: node.js, wordpress, cookies, jwt

(First, please note I've checked similar questions and haven't found any answers.)

## The situation

**I have a Wordpress site**, that I want to turn into a **membership site** (someone in my team will probably choose a plugin for that part). Lets say my site is called mysite.com.

On my subdomain app.mysite.com, I have a **Node.js + NestJS** hosted on **Heroku** that will also require a login to access some protected routes.

## What I'd like to do

Once a user signs up or signs in in mysite.com (the WP site), I want to find a way to have him still connected and recognized when he goes to app.mysite.com (the Node.js/Heroku site), without needing to ask him his email and password again.

**Is there a secure way to do this?** I'm having a hard time figuring out if I could do this using cookies or JWT tokens, since these are two different sites hosted on two different parts.

I also thought about **other possible solutions**:

- after a user signs up on the WP site (via the membership plugin), have the WP site call an API on the subdomain (Node/Heroku). But I'm not sure there are hooks that allow this call, and if the password could be passed through the API (is this possible? is this even secure?). And also: what if the user updates his password? if he is deleted? if his password has expired. That would mean extra use cases to handle and extra API calls, right?
- have a login form on my subdomain that under the hoods calls Wordpress REST Api to authenticate, but that means having the user enter his login twice (at least upon signup). I'd like to avoid this.

Any other idea?

I hope somebody around here can help me!

Thanks in advance, much appreciated.

Comment: what if you would use your node instance as the main source for logging in (so you don't need to deal with duplicate accounts etc)
That should massively simplify the part of dealing with sharing authentication.
It will complicate the wordpress side a bit however.

So even when someone creates an account on the WP site, it's actually creating all of it in the node instance?

Comment: Hi, thanks. Well the idea was to take advantage of some kind of memebership plugin on Wordpress side and avoid recoding all this on the node side (and just have some kind of SSO login).